# Inserting datetime value including milliseconds into mysql database from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am developing a web application using PHP laravel framework. What I am doing now is I am trying to insert datetime value including milliseconds which is given by the user. But it is throwing invalid datetime format error.

This is my code

```
$image = new Image;
$image->date_taken = date('Y-m-d H:i:s u',strtotime($date_and_time." ".$milliseconds)); //milliseconds is something like 0, 435, 455656
$image->save();
```

When I run the code, it is giving me this error.

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "1970-01-01 00:00:00 000000" (SQL: insert into "images" ("event_id", "user_id", "visibility", "s3_path", "file_hash", "date_taken", "taken_at_tag", "updated_at", "created_at") values (1, 101, 1, RWGV7HMW/iljimae.ic@gmail.com/wPxi5AkW0VzUfc0e5Xu4xQw27sdVXttAqMWUU1Cx.jpeg, ca5544c371b7c6a0eedc03b04e44f36f, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 000000, 124216-097, 2018-05-23 15:32:02, 2018-05-23 15:32:02) returning "id")
```

How can I format the datetime including milliseconds and insert into MySQL database?

Comment: What does the 'u' stand for in this line of code `$image->date_taken = date('Y-m-d H:i:s u'`

Comment: For milliseconds.

Comment: `u` is microseconds, `v` is milliseconds. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I think the correct format would be `Y-m-d H:i:s.u` or `Y-m-d H:i:s.v`. Note the period between the seconds and the micro/milliseconds.

Comment: Yes. You are right. The last comment helped me.

Answer (score 0):

What data type did you use when creating the table?

For Example:
DATE - format YYYY-MM-DD.

DATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.

SMALLDATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.

TIMESTAMP - format: a unique number.

source:https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp

Comment: Sorry. Actually i used timestamp. Which format should I use?

Comment: Really just depends what it's for. TimeStamp is more of a records kind of thing.

Comment: How can I insert milliseconds now?

Comment: You'll have to modify the column in the existing table or recreate the table. TimeStamp Format: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html